# Is it true that the plural of "chad" is "chadim"?

Tags: vocabulary, grammatical-number, terminology

I was busy at filing tasks today, working the hole punch and manufacturing... er... more than one *chad*. I consulted the *Computer Contradictionary* by Stan Kelly-Bootle, which is normally a reliable source for this sort of thing, and it claims that the plural of *chad* is *chadim*.

It referred me to the [*New Hacker's Dictionary*](http://www.eps.mcgill.ca/jargon/jargon.html) and the [*Jargon File*](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/chad.html)  which are sadly silent on the plural.

Does anyone know if *chadim* is a recognised plural (even among the *l33t haXor* community) or is this another of Kelly-Bootle's jokes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see it's an original joke.
I think it's based on Hebrew plurals ending in "-im"

There is a similar set of computer puns based on the "-en" plural, a network of VAX computers is a herd of Vaxen (cf. Oxen)

Comment: I might be reading too much into this since  Stan Kelly-Bootle is a scouser who has also written books on Liverpool slang.

Answer (score 6):

Back when people actually used punch cards, *chad* was a mass noun: when the chad bucket is full of chad, you empty it. During the 2000 presidential recount, the news media was introduced to the term and, having never heard otherwise, decided it was a countable noun instead, with plural *chads*.

Today it hardly seems worth arguing about, like debating what the plural of *Telex* should be. Call it what you want.

Comment: Perhaps you can answer the real mystery here: where the word *chad* originates?

Comment: Alas, the story about the fellow named Chadless who invented a "clean" keypunch [appears to be a myth](http://www.snopes.com/business/names/chad.asp).

Answer (score 3):

No it is not true.  The plural is **chads**.

*Washington Post, 2000*:

> counting as votes a large number of ballots with " dimpled " **chads** -- small indentations that did not detach the chad

*AP, 2000*:

> the antiquated voting systems that gave us dimpled **chads** and butterfly ballots.

Many more where those came from.  The word "chadim" does not occur in COCA.

Answer (score 3):

The *New Oxford American Dictionary* doesn’t list an unusual plural, it is thus *chads*.

Now, answering your unanswered question, about the etymology of this word:

> 1930s: possibly from Scots *chad* [gravel; small stones] or dialect *chat* [chip of wood.] It is not, as suggested, from the name of Mr. Chadless, inventor of a Chadless Keypunch, no such person has been found. Nor is it formed as an acronym from [card hole aggregate debris.]

Answer (score 1):

Chad and chads are both proper plural.  However, if you wish to stay true to its origin, then "chad" is both singular and plural.